# Connecting to BT LE device using org.bluez.Adapter.CreateDevice fails with org.bluez.Error.Failed: Operation canceled Error

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

I'm trying to set up a connection to a Bluetooth 4.0 LE device on Linux using the BlueZ 4.X  DBus interface.

To test this I use the following command:

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --print-reply /org/bluez/<PID of bluetoothd>/hci0 org.bluez.Adapter.CreateDevice string:<MAC of BT device>
```

This command seems to work most times, giving a result like:

```
method return sender=:1.238 -> dest=:1.262 reply_serial=2
   object path "/org/bluez/9652/hci1/dev_BC_6A_29_26_C2_1C"
```

and enabling me to interact with the device DBus object.

However, starting from yesterday, this seems to fail very frequently returning the following error:

```
Error org.bluez.Error.Failed: Operation canceled
```

When debugging the bluetooth daemon, (using `bluetoothd -n -d`) I notice the following things when executing the method call:

```
bluetoothd[340]: src/adapter.c:create_device() BC:6A:29:26:C2:1C
bluetoothd[340]: src/adapter.c:adapter_create_device() BC:6A:29:26:C2:1C
bluetoothd[340]: src/device.c:device_create() Creating device /org/bluez/340/hci0/dev_BC_6A_29_26_C2_1C
bluetoothd[340]: src/device.c:btd_device_ref() 0xb7ad8: ref=1
bluetoothd[340]: src/device.c:device_set_temporary() temporary 1
bluetoothd[340]: src/device.c:btd_device_ref() 0xb7ad8: ref=2
bluetoothd[340]: plugins/mgmtops.c:mgmt_event() cond 1
bluetoothd[340]: plugins/mgmtops.c:mgmt_event() Received 14 bytes from management socket
bluetoothd[340]: plugins/mgmtops.c:mgmt_connect_failed() hci0 BC:6A:29:26:C2:1C status 4
bluetoothd[340]: src/event.c:btd_event_conn_failed() status 0x04
bluetoothd[340]: src/device.c:device_remove() Removing device /org/bluez/340/hci0/dev_BC_6A_29_26_C2_1C
bluetoothd[340]: src/device.c:device_set_temporary() temporary 1
bluetoothd[340]: src/device.c:btd_device_unref() 0xb7ad8: ref=1
bluetoothd[340]: src/device.c:btd_device_unref() 0xb7ad8: ref=0
bluetoothd[340]: src/device.c:device_free() 0xb7ad8
```

As far as I can see, my Bluetooth dongle sends me an error event (status 4) when I try to connect to the device.

However, when I use hcitool ot gatttool to connect to the device, everything works perfectly.

I found that this happens mostly after I try to connect to the device using a different program (i.e cinnamon-settings), and cancel the connection prematurely. I also noticed this with other programs like bluetooth-properties on Angstrom.

My guess is that Bluez sends the wrong HCI commands to my bluetooth dongle in certain conditions. I think this is because the gui programs try to pair with the device instead of just connecting to it, which may cause BlueZ to think my device is a Bluetooth 2.0 device.

Thus far I seemed to be able to resolve this problem by connecting to my BT device using a gui application, waiting till it fails, and restarting my computer. However, the problem seems to reoccur occasionally, making this very painful.

I have seen this problem on systems running both BlueZ version 4.99 and 4.101.

Does anyone know how I can solve this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like my predictions where more or less correct. After many hours of debugging the Bluetooth daemon I discovered that connecting to BT LE devices without a preliminary scan causes the daemon to try to connect to the device as a BR/EDR device. This is because the daemon's "internal cache" is filled with the [EIR](http://docs.huihoo.com/symbian/nokia-symbian3-developers-library-v0.8/GUID-F2A793F1-A5B5-526B-B147-771D440B13A2.html) information at the time the device is discovered. If this information is not available when connecting to a LE device the CreateDevice method will fail.

A simple solution is to always make sure to discover devices before connecting to them.

The [BlueZ 5 API introduction and porting guide](http://www.bluez.org/bluez-5-api-introduction-and-porting-guide/) also describes this problem, and how it is solved in BlueZ 5:

> Bluetooth Low Energy essentially extended Bluetooth addresses with one extra bit, requiring one to always know whether an address is “random” or “public”. This caused issues with the BlueZ 4 API where the address was given to BlueZ in the CreateDevice and CreatePairedDevice calls. Since the parameter didn’t contain any of this extra random/public information bluetoothd had to maintain an internal cache to look up the necessary info. Another complication to the matter is that the BlueZ D-Bus API doesn’t differentiate between traditional BR/EDR devices and LE devices so there are essentially three possible address types: BR/EDR, LE public and LE random.